# Point a Windows Server to one specific AD Server?

Tags: active-directory

It is possible to point a server/client to one specific AD Server?
Is a host entry the solution?

Environment: domain.local running on Server A and B

Edit

This is my problem:

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do this as it gives a single point of failure... If the AD on that machine goes down then it'll take the clients with it. Best practice is redundancy and to have the servers replicating.

Comment: Your DCs arent virtual machines are they?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to allow windows to pick its own DC at boot using sites and services.  When a machine starts, it searches for its own AD site (based on IP Range) and then looks for A DC assigned to that site.

if you REALLY want to point to a specific DC (and I can't think of a reason why you would!), you have several possibilities:

1)**Hosts file** as you mentioned - but this gives a single point of failure

2)**Use IP Security to filter out the DC you don't want**:

- mmc > add snapIn "IP Security Policy management"
- filter out all evil DCs by IP (search google if unable to create and assign policy)
- on Client PC's DNS setting manually put the Holy DC's IP
- Restart PC and login.
- If successful > open CMD > type echo %logonserver% to check which DC it is pointing.

3)**Add a new IP Range to your network, assign it to a new AD site and move the DC you dont want to use onto it.**  This will make your clients go to your preferred DC (same Subnet) and then fallback to the other one if the preferred DC is out of contact
[This Technet Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc754697.aspx) point you in the direction you will need to go to configre a site, assign a subnet to it and setup replication

---

I must question why it is that you want to force someone to a specific DC when they should both be in sync and have the exact same data on them.  If this is because you are writing an application that needs to point to a domain controller - you should instead consider:

**Binding to the root DSE** for your script and letting the script figure out which DC it wants to talk to - or - **Create a Round Robin DNS Record** which contains the IPs of both DCs and then pointing you appliocation at that host name.

Comment: I updated my question...